# Retain Datagrid multiselection after it is updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, selection

I'm developing a WPF application and use the mvvm light toolkit. My viewmodel consists of a timer which updates an ObservableCollection. Additionally I have a ListCollectionView.

```
ObservableCollection<MyType> obs = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
ListCollectionView cView = new ListCollectionView(obs);

public void timer_elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(myOperation == add)
        obs.InsertItem(0, newObject);

    else if(myOperation == remove)
        obs[...].Close();

    else if(myOperation == modify)
        obs[...] = newObject;
}
```

In my view, I bind a datagrid to the ListCollectionView:

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding cView}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    / >
```

Whenever the ObservableCollection is changed by one of the operations in the timer, the ListCollectionView is changed as well, and so is the content of the datagrid. 
I can select multiple rows between the changes, but as soon as the datagrids content is changed my selections get lost.

How do I retain all of my datagrids selections, even if its content is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just take an account of the selected items before the update?  After the updates, repopulate the selected `SelectedItems` list as needed.

This is a bit of a challenge from an MVVM standpoint, because `SelectedItems` is not a dependency property.  But use your view-viewmodel communication method of choice -- passing view items into the viewmodel, event aggregator, whichever.

Example for completeness:

**View model**

```
public Func<IList> GetSelectedItems { get; set; }

public void timer_elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var previouslySelectedItems = new List<MyType>(GetSelectedItems().OfType<MyType>());

    // .... updates

    var currentSelectedItems = GetSelectedItems();
    foreach (var selected in previouslySelectedItems) 
        if (!currentSelectedItems.Contains(selected))
            currentSelectedItems.Add(selected);
}
```

**View**

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComonent
    Loaded += (sender, args) => 
        ((MyViewModel)DataContext).GetSelectedItems = () => grid.SelectedItems;
}
```